# PHP adding value to some but not all iterations of foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

beginner programmer here.

I have pictures in a directory that are pushed into an array

```
$pressImages = scandir('img/press');
```

then sliced to remove system files

```
$slice = array_slice($pressImages, 3);
```

then run through a loop to print out each image on to the webpage

```
foreach ($slice as $image) {
 echo "<div class='press list-item'><img src='img/press/$image' /></div>";
}
```

I would like to add anchor tags to the first four iterations of the loop (each Link is unique), but not to the others. I'm trying to learn how to consolidate instructions to the smallest number possible. Would I need to create two separate loops here? I was thinking I would create two directories, one for images that have links, and the other for images without links, with each having their own foreach loop, but my intuition suggests there might be a more efficient way.

Thanks for the help in advance!

**Some wonderful suggestions everyone thanks again, learning so much. I've been unable to try these out myself so am relying on visualizing them. I will be sure to select an answer soon

Comment: also you dont have to assign value after array_slice use the same $pressImages as it slices that array so as to reduce variables

Comment: @Rohitshah thanks very helpful did not think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this "functional style" with [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
array_walk($images, function ($image, $_, &$count) {
    $count += 1;

    $image = "<img src='img/press/$image'/>";

    if ($count <= 4) {
        $image = "<a href='#'>$image</a>";
    }

    echo "<div class='press list-item'>$image</div>", PHP_EOL;
}, 0);
```

You can notice that I have used only `if` without `else`. It is a good practice in PHP (and many other languages). For example, you should take a look at such great tool as [PHP Mess Detector](https://phpmd.org/rules/cleancode.html). There is a rule about this:

> An if expression with an else branch is never necessary. You can
>   rewrite the conditions in a way that the else is not necessary and the
>   code becomes simpler to read. To achieve this use early return
>   statements. To achieve this you may need to split the code it several
>   smaller methods. For very simple assignments you could also use the
>   ternary operations.

And here is a [working demo of my solution](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/119a1b323ed88a7606993ff2a19f53fc3d591321).

`PHP_EOL` in the `echo` is added only for the purpose of result presentation. Feel free to remove it.

Also, be aware that you cannot always rely on array key as on counter. Off the top of head example would be when you need to sort images, then the indexes won't be in order.

ADDITION:

If you have two arrays: `$images` and `$links`, and they can be linked with the order of appearance, then you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
array_map(function ($image, $link) {
    $image = "<img src='img/press/$image'/>";

    if ($link) {
        $image = "<a href='$link'>$image</a>";
    }

    // Or you can return string here and array_map will 
    // create an array of all resulting images.
    echo "<div class='press list-item'>$image</div>", PHP_EOL;
}, $images, $links);
```

The reason to use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is that you can supply more than one array and traverse them in parallel.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b88e1a40357bbec182b6264c980c53c44fdb3463).

Comment: Interesting way of attacking this. Could we use the same  counter like stated above to deal with the fact that the links are unique? See my comments on thmspl's answer. Thank you!

Comment: @fd1247, if you have two arrays and your approach is: `n` links from the array of length `n` go for first `n` images from the array of images, then you don't need counter at all.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

You can use foreach key instead like this (see [Official PHP foreach docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)):

```
foreach ($slice as $key => $image) {
    if($key > 3) {
        echo "<div class='press list-item'><img src='' /></div>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='your_link_here'><div class='press list-item'><img src='img/press/$image' /></div></a>";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is just an alternative to using `array_slice` and does not answer the question, which is about altering the html for the 1st 4 items in the array

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: I like this answer in my head. But I should of specified anchor tags so the image is clickable, not different file paths. How would you do this with unique anchor hrefs? (Editing OP to say anchor tags)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a counter that you increment, and use an if block:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($slice as $image) {
    $count++;
    if($count <= 4){
        echo 'your link html here';
    }else{
        echo 'your non link html here';
    }
}
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
$count = 4;
foreach ($slice as $image) {
    if($count--){
        echo 'your link html here';
        break;
    }
    echo 'your non link html here';
}
```

Comment: The second loop will run only once. I guess `continue;` was meant instead of `break;`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the link everytime the same?

```
foreach ($slice as $count => $image) {
    if($count > 3){
        echo "<div class='press list-item'><a href='#'><img src='img/press/$image' /></a></div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div class='press list-item'><img src='img/press/$image' /></div>";
    }
}
```

If I undstand your question correctly this would work for you.

Comment: The links would be different for each one, I'll add that to the initial question thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Same as Saumyas idea, i think I like this. But the urls are unique. What do you two think of adding the urls into an array, and using a counter variable to select the proper link path respective to the current iteration (iteration 2 picks link in index 1).